# `stack ghci` fails when you include a project which imports Gloss

Tags: haskell, ghci, haskell-stack, gloss

If you import Gloss within a Stack project and use `stack ghci`, you get the following error:

```
GHCi, version 7.10.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
<command line>: can't load .so/.DLL for: /Users/v/hs/.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/lts-3.7/7.10.2/lib/x86_64-osx-ghc-7.10.2/GLUT-2.7.0.3-FFXiDYE1CfiDHjNKroBerv/libHSGLUT-2.7.0.3-FFXiDYE1CfiDHjNKroBerv-ghc7.10.2.dylib (dlopen(/Users/v/hs/.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/lts-3.7/7.10.2/lib/x86_64-osx-ghc-7.10.2/GLUT-2.7.0.3-FFXiDYE1CfiDHjNKroBerv/libHSGLUT-2.7.0.3-FFXiDYE1CfiDHjNKroBerv-ghc7.10.2.dylib, 5): Symbol not found: _glutBitmap8By13
  Referenced from: /Users/v/hs/.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/lts-3.7/7.10.2/lib/x86_64-osx-ghc-7.10.2/GLUT-2.7.0.3-FFXiDYE1CfiDHjNKroBerv/libHSGLUT-2.7.0.3-FFXiDYE1CfiDHjNKroBerv-ghc7.10.2.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/v/hs/.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/lts-3.7/7.10.2/lib/x86_64-osx-ghc-7.10.2/GLUT-2.7.0.3-FFXiDYE1CfiDHjNKroBerv/libHSGLUT-2.7.0.3-FFXiDYE1CfiDHjNKroBerv-ghc7.10.2.dylib)
```

How can that be fixed?

Comment: have you opened an issue for this on https://github.com/benl23x5/gloss / http://gloss.ouroborus.net?

Comment: Sad thing their repository doesn't have an issue forum. I'll eventually try the official ticket system on their site. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried this in my system and it worked:

```
cabal install GLUT --ghc-options="-optl-Wl,-framework,GLUT" --reinstall --jobs=1
```

I found this solution here: [Trouble building applications with Haskell GLUT and freeglut on OS X with GHC 7.10.1](https://github.com/haskell-opengl/GLUT/issues/19)